# What's the worst defeat of a host nation in World Cup history?

Tags: football, trivia, history, statistics, world-cup

Brazil, the host nation of the 2014 FIFA World Cup, [lost to Germany 7-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil_v_Germany_(2014_FIFA_World_Cup)). This seems like a very big defeat in term of goal difference. What is the worst defeat of a host nation in World Cup history in terms of goal difference?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, this was the worst defeat of a host nation in the history of the world cup!
Other notable defeats are:

- 2010: [South Africa 0 - 3 Uruguay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_A#South_Africa_vs_Uruguay)
- 1958: [Sweden 2 - 5 Brazil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1958_FIFA_World_Cup_Final)

Link: [World Cup 2014: Most Lopsided Football Matches, Worst Host Defeat, Biggest Soccer Blowouts in History](http://www.theepochtimes.com/n3/793597-world-cup-2014-most-lopsided-football-matches-biggest-soccer-blowouts-in-history/) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907032202/http://www.theepochtimes.com/n3/793597-world-cup-2014-most-lopsided-football-matches-biggest-soccer-blowouts-in-history/))`

Answer (score 13):

Looking at the statistics of [all World Cup matches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Cup), this is the worst defeat of a host nation in World Cup history in terms of goal difference. This is also the worst defeat by a host nation in terms of goals conceded, jointly with [Switzerland losing 5-7 against Austria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austria_v_Switzerland_(1954_FIFA_World_Cup)) in 1954.